# Gmail scrollbar disappears

Tags: gmail-labels, firefox

There is a *feature* of Gmail that drives me nuts.  I have a lot of labels.  Some of them are listed in a sidebar on the left.  The scrollbar behaves like the Cheshire Cat from *Alice in Wonderland*.  I would like it to remain visible all the time.  How can I do that?

If it helps -- I typically work with Gmail in Firefox.

Comment: "There is a feature of Gmail that drives me nuts. I have a lot of labels. Some of them are listed in a sidebar on the left. The scrollbar behaves like the Cheshire Cat from Alice in Wonderland. I would like it to remain visible all the time."  -- What scrollbar? The scrollbar on the left or the right? What do you mean by "The scrollbar behaves like the Cheshire Cat from Alice in Wonderland"?

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin - I am sorry I missed your comment previously.  The scrollbar is to the right of the list of labels, which is itself on the left edge of the screen.  The Cheshire Cat disappears and reappears.  It is mentioned in a classic of English children's literature, *Alice in Wonderland* (or maybe the sequel, I forget which), by Lewis Carroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct method, no. But, using a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) or [Firefox Add-On](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) you can change the CSS styles to the following:

Domain: `https://mail.google.com/*`

CSS:

```
.aeN .ajl { overflow-y: scroll;}
```

This will "add" the vertical scrollbar by overriding Google's CSS in Gmail. Note that Google hides the labels beyond the initial list, so you'll need to click "More" at the bottom to open all of the labels.

Comment: It worked like a charm.